# Windows Permissions code: confusing answers while fetching the ACEs

Tags: windows, winapi, file-permissions, dacl

While implementing a piece code to fetch the ACE's for owner and group, I am using [this](https://github.com/MagnusTiberius/win32acl/blob/master/win32acl.cpp) code as an inspiration.

To test this code, I created a file in a folder.

In an elevated command prompt, I run the app (exe created from above code) with file name as an input and see the output which is as below

```
C:\>C:\Users\user\Documents\VS2017\Project4\Debug\Project4.exe C:\Deny\file.txt
file:C:\Deny\file.txt
Owner: DOMAIN/user
Group: DOMAIN/user

::DACL::
GetAce Output : 1
SID: DOMAIN/user
ACE: mask:2032127 sidStart:1281 header type=1 header flags=0
 DELETE
 FILE_GENERIC_READ
 FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
 FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE
 READ_CONTROL
 WRITE_DAC
 WRITE_OWNER
 SYNCHRONIZE

::SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_CONTROL::
 SE_DACL_PRESENT
 SE_DACL_PROTECTED
 SE_SELF_RELATIVE
```

I right click the same file and in the security settings, I deny all the permissions to the file for the same user.

I again run the app on this file and I still get the same output

```
C:\>C:\Users\user\Documents\VS2017\Project4\Debug\Project4.exe C:\Deny\file.txt
file:C:\Deny\file.txt
Owner: DOMAIN/user
Group: DOMAIN/user

::DACL::
GetAce Output : 1
SID: DOMAIN/user
ACE: mask:2032127 sidStart:1281 header type=1 header flags=0
 DELETE
 FILE_GENERIC_READ
 FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
 FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE
 READ_CONTROL
 WRITE_DAC
 WRITE_OWNER
 SYNCHRONIZE

::SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_CONTROL::
 SE_DACL_PRESENT
 SE_DACL_PROTECTED
 SE_SELF_RELATIVE
```

Am I missing something ? 
I tried to understand this code and I could not figure out any obvious mistakes.

Comment: When you say you are using the github code for inspiration, what exactly are you running? Or are you saying the right click to set permissions isn't working?

Comment: I used above code and created an exe. I ran it on a file and got the output. I changed the permissions on the file using "Right Click -> Security Settings-> Change Permissions". I ran the exe again on the same file. and I got the same output. I think the "Right Click -> Security Settings-> Change Permissions" is working fine as when I try to open this file, I get a message box saying I can not open the same as I lack permissions.

Comment: Explorer itself does not run in elevated mode, so the permissions you may get from an elevated app might be different.

Comment: @Michael If I run this from normal (not elevated) command prompt, I get the same output, except for last part of "SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_CONTROL" . That part is missing.

Comment: Both results have "header type=1", i.e. [`AccessDenied`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.acetype?view=netframework-4.7.2).